# How to use a FOR loop check if a list of strings has letter a certain letter inside them?

Tags: python-3.x

for example,

if i were to use the list: List= ['hQTsk', 'MXqoP', 'FmErkX']

how would i use a FOR Loop to check if the strings in the list contain the letter 'k' and then display the string and weather or not it has the letter 'k'.
My first attempt was:

```
for strings in List:
    if any('k' in strings):
            print(str(strings) + " has the letter 'k'")
    else:
            print(str(strings) + " doesn't have the letter 'k'")
```

and i don't know why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `any`:

```
if 'k' in strings:
```